# html radio button not POSTing

Tags: php, html, forms

I am using a form with radio buttons to post a value to PHP. However, the value is not being sent. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<form action="voteupdate.php" id="form-id" method="post"onclick="document.getElementById(\'form-id\').submit();">  
  <input type="hidden" name="type" id="type" value="' . $type . '">  
  <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="' . $id . '">  
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">  
    <label class="btn btn-default '.$vup.'">  
        <input type="radio" name="vote" id="1" value="1">  
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span> Vote up  
     </label>  
    <label class="btn btn-default '.$vd.'">  
        <input type="radio" name="vote" id="2" value="2">  
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> Vote down  
    </label>  
</div>  
  </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php session_start();   
include('config.php');  
  $type = $_POST['type'];  
  $id = $_POST['id'];  
  echo $_POST['vote'];  
    if ($type == "images"){  
  $tid = "imgid";  
  }  
    if ($type == "pages"){  
  $tid = "pageid";  
  }  
    if ($type == "posts"){  
  $tid = "postid";  
  }  
$table = str_replace(""," ",$type);  
$table = str_replace('"'," ",$table);  
$table = str_replace("'"," ",$table);  
$stmt= $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM '".$table."' WHERE ".$tid." = :imgid");  
$stmt->execute(array(':imgid' => $id));  
$stmt = $stmt->fetch();  

$vreg = explode(",", $stmt['votereg']);  
foreach ($vreg as $v) {  
$temp = explode("-", $v);  
if ($_SESSION['uid'] == $temp['0']){  
if (1 == $temp['1']){  
header( 'Location: votesys.php' ) ;  
}  
else  
{  
$instruction = "update-exists";  
}  
}  
    }  
    echo $instruction;  
?>
```

Comment: please paste code here in future

Comment: So you meant to say that `$_POST['vote']` is empty? I notice you are not actually using it in your PHP except `echo $_POST['vote']`

Comment: If this is your exact code copied, the typo/lack of space between "post" and onclick is causing it to not send as post, so the _POST array would be indeed empty. Try putting a print_r($_GET) and print_r($_POST) and see what is coming in where

Comment: It isn't in scope of this question, but your sanitization of `$table` is not sufficient if it originates from user input.  Replacing quotes with spaces still leaves the possibility of sending faulty SQL.  If that's user input, check it against an array of permissible values, and don't proceed if it isn't in the whitelist.

Comment: Remove onclick="document.getElementById(\'form-id\').submit();" - you don't need it

Comment: Your code works for me. How do you submit a form without submit button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form action="voteupdate.php" id="form-id" method="post"onclick="document.getElementById(\'form-id\').submit();">
```

is missing a space between method and onclick attributes:

```
<form action="voteupdate.php" id="form-id" method="post" onclick="document.getElementById(\'form-id\').submit();">
```

Comment: no did not try it, but it will give problems in some browsers, just noticed something: the onclick function should not be there.

Comment: It will work without onclick - it's not necessary at all. Parasite code.

Comment: space missing is a typo

Comment: @user4035 doesn't that send the form empty because you click it?

Comment: @GertB. Oh, gosh, I think you are right. I have never seen such a strange method of form submitting: creating onclick event on form tag. He doesn't use <submit> button. Most probably, this is the cause.